# Android Drawables not Refreshing

Tags: android, drawable

I have this issue that is driving me crazy lately...

I have an app full of drawable assets (backgrounds, images, etc).
After testing on a larger device, I found out some drawables are too small and became stretched.
Then, I decided to make higher-quality versions of them and then replace them on the drawable folder.
After I launch the app on the device, I noticed the drawables didn't refresh, leaving the app with the old ones.
I tried to uninstall the app, no difference... after I install it again, the app comes with all the old stuff instead of the new one.

What is happening? :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Project/Clean, and deploy your application.
If the problem persists, the other possibility is that you didn't split /drawable into /drawable-hdpi, /drawable-ldpi, /drawable-mdpi, /drawable-xhdpi.

Comment: thank you for the fast response! cleaning the project actually works!

Comment: although this might have solved your issue I would suggest you to keep your smaller drawables on drawable-ldpi folder or drawable-mdpi folder and to use your larger drawables in drawable-hdpi or drawable-xhdpi so you can keep screen compatibility with lower pixel density screens

Answer (score 1):

Try to refresh drawable folder (right click on it -> refresh) If that won't help, temporary set a reference to another picture run your application. Then exit it and set back the reference to the correct picture.

Answer (score 1):

If Clean Project doesn't work for you, try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` -- that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

None of that solutions worked for me.

It worked just after I renamed the files and changed the references to the drawables on the code.